# Insert Double quotes as string

Tags: java, mysql, string, double-quotes

```
else if(error.equals("Duplicate entry"for key 'PRIMARY'"));
```

In the above code, I want to insert the " after entry as a string but it is not letting me to do so, please help.

Comment: escape it with `\\`

Comment: "Duplicate entry\"for key 'PRIMARY'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the escape character

```
else if(error.equals("Duplicate entry\"for key \"PRIMARY\""));
```